# Can't find correct path to "static" files in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Having a heck of a time running a Flask app where I've changed the "root" of the site to be a "subdirectory" url using ProxyPass with Gunicorn and Apache.

I have the site loading at https://example.com/flaskapp finally, but all of my static files return 404's. No combination of url structure has allowed me to view a file in the browser (like a .css file for example).

I have:

```
* flaskapp (project folder)
    * app (main folder)
        * __init__.py
        * views.py
        * controllers.py
        * static
        * templates
    * venv
    * requirements.txt
```

I launch gunicorn with: `gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000`

My **init**.py file contains:

```
from flask import Flask

import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.debug')
    logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)

# Initialize the app
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, static_url_path='', static_folder='static')

# Load the config file
app.config.from_pyfile('app.cfg')

from app import controllers
from app import views

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=app.config['DEBUG'])
```

In one of my html files, here is how I'm attempting to include a .css file:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Because the site is running at "/flaskapp" as root, I think there's something wrong with the URL's or something I'm not setting up properly for the static routes.

EDIT: Here is how I have my .conf set up in Apache to proxy

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /flaskapp http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /flaskapp http://localhost:8000/
Timeout 2400
ProxyTimeout 240
```

Where am I going wrong with setting this up properly?

Answer (score 0):

here's my code to load static file and cache to memory

```
STATIC_FILE = {}
def load_file(file_name):
    ext = file_name.split(".")[-1]
    if file_name not in STATIC_FILE:
        with open("./public{}".format(file_name), 'rb') as file:
            STATIC_FILE[file_name] = file.read()
    return STATIC_FILE[file_name]

MIME_TYPE = {"js": "text/javascript", "css": "text/css", "png": "image/png", "woff": "font/woff", "woff2": "font/woff2"}
@app.route('/assets/<path:path>')
def assets(path):
    ext = path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[-1]
    return Response(load_file(path), mimetype=MIME_TYPE[ext])

// access via /assets/css/style.css if your file in ./public/assets/css/style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved this by removing the extra parameters from my main app initialization line:

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
```

Then, when referencing in the html, I simply used:

```
<link href="static/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This seems to be doing the trick. I'm not sure why the "running from a subdomain" was throwing me off so much.